# Concatenar un integer con todos los valores de una columna en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito concatenar un valor con todos los valores de una columna de Oracle.
Adjunto dos imagenes que aclararan el problema:

1- Tabla que quiero modificar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2- Como necesito que quede despues de hacer el update:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He pensado en:

```
UPDATE [TABLA] SET FECHA = 29 || FECHA;
```

Si no estoy equivocado, la tabla quedaria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podeis ayudarme?

Comment: O sea.. tenes que cambiar el dia de todos los registros? de que tipo es el campo?

Comment: puedes hacer `TO_DATE(29||SUBSTR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),3),'DD-MON-YY') ` o `trunc(sysdate,'MM') + (29-1)`

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, correcto seria eso. El campo es tipo Date.

Comment: Si la columna FECHA es de tipo DATE entonces lo que ud. desea es actualizar el DIA de una fecha para que sea el mismo DIA para todos los registros o un conjunto de registros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
TO_DATE(29||SUBSTR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),3),'DD-MON-YY')
```

`TRUNC(SYSDATE)` devuelve la fecha truncada, `SUBSTR()` lo que hace es cortar la cadena ejemplo `15-JUL-20` quedaria `-JUL-20` a esto le concatenamos el dia que queremos `29` y quedaria `29-JUL-20` ahora lo pasamos a formato de fecha nuevamente en el formato que deseamos con `TO_DATE()`.

```
trunc(sysdate,'MM') + (29-1)
```

`TRUNC(SYSDATE,"MM")` devuelve el primer dia del mes
a esto se le suma la cantidad de dia que deseas
`TRUNC(SYSDATE,"MM")` =1 +(29-1) = 29

## resultado

```
SQL> select TO_DATE(29||SUBSTR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),3),'DD-MON-YY')  from dual;

TO_DATE(2
---------
29-JUL-20

SQL> select trunc(sysdate,'MM') + (29-1) from dual;

TRUNC(SYS
---------
29-JUL-20

SQL>
```

Comment: Hola @Bryro, no termina de quedarme claro. La salida que muestras no tiene el formato igual 29/07/2020 con /

Comment: es un ejemplo cambias `sysdate` por tu el campo `fecha`  y lo adaptas a tu consulta luego lo metes dentro de un parentersis y le das `set fecha = (select.... )` para actualizar todos los datos si asi lo deseas

Comment: creo que me decido por esta: set fecha = (select trunc(fecha,'MM') + (29-1) from dual);  ¿Podrias describirme que hace cada parte de la query? Gracias

Comment: `trunc(fecha,"MM")` devuelve ell primer dia del mes y luego le sumas los días que necesites como devuelve 1 si le sumas los dias daria 30 entonces le sumas ( 29-1 ) y le resta el dia para que quede en dia 29 y no 30!

Comment: o esa.. le sumas 28??? es una forma rara de sumar 28....

Comment: exacto! asi mismo porque si devuelve 1

Answer (score 1):

1-En Oracle una columna de tipo DATE siempre se tiene fecha y tiempo:
año
mes
dia
hora
minutos
segundos

2-En Oracle una columna de tipo DATE en sí misma NO tiene formato.

3-Lo que se ve en una pantalla es resultado de la configuración regional del cliente o del IDE que se esté usando, y esa configuración se puede cambiar por cada sesión.

Dicho lo anterior, entonces el update puede ser:

```
update mi_tabla
set fecha=to_date(to_char(fecha,'yyyy-mm')
                  ||'-29 '
                  ||to_char(fecha,'hh24:mi:ss'),
                  'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
                  )
where a in ('Casa','Piso','Compra','Coche');
```

Explicación:

```
1-to_char(fecha,'yyyy-mm'):  
Obtener un string con el año (de 4 dígitos) y el mes de 2 dígitos 

2.||'-29 '  
Concatenar el día que desea  

3- to_char(fecha,'hh24:mi:ss'),:  
Concatenar con el string de la hora en 24 horas, los minutos y segundos  

4-to_date(:  
Aplicar la función do_date para obtener un valor de tipo DATE

5-como el string está en el estándar internacional ISO-8601,
  entonces el 2º parámetro que es el formato es 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
```

[norma ISO 8601](http://formato%20internacional%20norma%20ISO-8601)